# move_uploaded_file() not working

Tags: php, html, file, move

I have a very simple file upload form and php script, however it doesn't appear to be working.

HTML:

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" action="upload_file.php">
    Send this file: <input name="userfile" type="file" /><br />
    <input type="submit" value="Send File" />
</form>
```

PHP:

```
<?php
    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'], "./upload")) {
        print "Received {$_FILES['userfile']['name']} - its size is {$_FILES['userfile']['size']}";
    } else {
        print "Upload failed!";
    }
?>
```

When I upload the file and visit the ''upload_file.php'' page I get this error:

> Warning: move_uploaded_file(): The second argument to copy() function
>   cannot be a directory in blahhhh/blahhhh/public_html/upload_file.php
>   on line 2 Warning: move_uploaded_file(): Unable to move
>   '/tmp/phprsYav7' to './upload' in
>   blahhhh/blahhhh//public_html/upload_file.php on line 2 Upload failed!

Any idea on how to fix this? Thanks!

Comment: Have you *read* the error message? You need to provide a *file path*, not just a directory. Something like `upload/foobar.jpg`, not just `upload`.

Comment: Here, read the `F` manual http://php.net/manual/en/function.move-uploaded-file.php - you're missing an argument. See example #1.

Comment: @deceze Oh I see, how would I get it so that the file name IS the 'tmp name' when uploaded in the ./upload directory? - if that's possible>

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify a filename and not just a path.  Something like this:

```
<?php
    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'], "./upload/blah.txt")) {
        print "Received {$_FILES['userfile']['name']} - its size is {$_FILES['userfile']['size']}";
    } else {
        print "Upload failed!";
    }
?>
```